# Category Page without plugins

Tags: jekyll, liquid

currently I have a Jekyll based site. The site was created about three years ago, but currently I have problems updating it. On the Site I have a blog. And in the navigation I have category pages for the blog.

To create a page for each category, I created a layout, where the layout is showing the posts for the matching category.

So I have a Page without any content for the category:

```
---
layout: category
title: Elektronik
category: elektronik
permalink: /blog/elektronik/index.html
---
```

And the Layout for category, where I go through the postings:

```
{% for post in site.categories.[page.category] %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

This solution worked before, but now the category page is clear and I get an error message during compilation:

```
Liquid Warning: Liquid syntax error (line 36): Expected id but found open_square in "post in site.categories.[page.category]" in /_layouts/category.html
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Try removing the dot: site.categories[page.category]

Comment: marcanuy, this does not work, because site.categories... is not an array but an object. So I need to access site.categories.Elektronik to get the pages under the "Elektronik" category

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'contains' in your for loop, like this:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% if post.categories contains page.category %}
    ...
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```